# Redirect Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

I'm looking to get a URL from a query. (The query is "?url=urlgoeshere" [where "urlgoeshere" is the URL to redirect to]) and redirect to that URL. For some reason when I run the script it goes to "http://mydomain.ext/urlgoeshere" (where "urlgoeshere" is the URL to redirect to)

Any ideas on how I could fix this issue?

This is my current code:

```js
    var loc = window.location.href;
    var url = window.location.search.split("?url=");
    var countdown=5
    var currentsecond=document.rd.box.value=countdown+1
    function redirect(){
     if (currentsecond!=1){
      currentsecond-=1
      document.rd.box.value=currentsecond
     } else {
      open(url);
      return
     }
     setTimeout("redirect()",1000)
    }
    redirect()
```

```html
<form name="rd">
<center>
<br><br><br><br>
<font face="Arial"><b>You will be redirected in<br><br>
<input type="text" size="3" name="box">
</form>
seconds</b></font>
</center>
```

Comment: Also, make sure that your URL starts with the protocol "http://"

Answer (score 0):

After splitting your url. Your url will be an array of two entries.

url[0] will be your current page url.

url[1] will be the url you want to redirect.

So in your code use the following:

```
  open(url[1])
```